# Stop caching of a particular element of a page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

Is they any way to stop caching of a particular element in a page, so that it always loads from the server? I have a div element in the page, which contains some session information that needs to be always updated/retrieved from the server.

My technology here is PHP/jQuery/Joomla.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When requesting with xmlhttprequest (ajax) one technique could be is to append a time-stamp value to the URL so each time the function is called the request is unique an  example could be

```
/// javascript get date convert it to milliseconds
 function getDateTime(){ 

     return (new Date().getTime());
 }
```

so in your ajax GET for example you could do so each request it appends a new time stamp

```
    req.onreadystatechange=function(){
    .....
    };

    req.open("GET",url+"?ac="+t+"&"+ getDateTime() ,true);
    req.send("");
```

Now since you using javascript you would beable to only display the "div's conten" only if js is enabled, thus forcing new content each, so embed a inline script and call a function to populate the div

```
   <script>populateDivsContent()</script>
```

Comment: actually that seems like a good idea, let me try that! load it through ajax

Comment: this solved the issue! not the easy way,but this is as good as it gets

Answer (score -1):

You can stop cache by using following piece of php code:

```
//Set no caching
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: does it apply to the whole page or a particular html element? this looks like a whole page case?

Comment: @ShroukHasanKhan: It applies to whole page, let's see if it is possible to remove cache from a div :)